# How to center text within a line

Tags: html, css

So i am trying to create a page separator with text between two horizontal lines. However, I am having difficulty getting the text to nest within the two lines.

Here is what I am working on in JSFIDDLE...[My work in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Ie0baulQMw)

Comment: That collaborative session is a mess. Can you post the jsfiddle to your original work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your css code :

```
.or{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/greenfox/mCvw8/)

Comment: Thanks man! worked like a charm

Comment: @RyanSalmons If you are satisfied with this then kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach than the answer, just in case.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <hr class="floatLeft splitHR" /> 
    <span class="floatLeft or"> OR </span>
    <hr class="floatLeft splitHR" />
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.floatLeft {
    float:left;
}
.splitHR {
    width: 45%;
}
.or {
    width: 9%;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
}
```